# Massive Crawling requests from Google Apps Engine useragent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm badly affected with 'Google AppEngine-Google' UserAgent.. receiving 5/6 requests per second on http server. This bot is crawling my site just like GoogleBot does.

Following is the sample of url in my access logs.

72.14.192.3 - - [19/May/2010:01:27:06 +0000] "GET /some-url/etc-123.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 4707 "-" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: harpy000)"

I have checked the ip address it is registered with Google Inc.

Can anyone tell me where i can report Abuse to Google Inc. Or any information about this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: you consider 5-6 requests per second abuse? WHat is your definition of low load? 1 request per minute? 5-6requests per second are not massive crawling, they are "no load".

Comment: :-), 5 to 6 requests per second doesn't impact any load but nobody would like illegal crawler.

Bad crawler should be block straight away. Rough analysis shows, he is a Developer hosted his application on Google AppEngine and and crawling data illegally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report Google App Engine abuse using the following form: http://code.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=AppEngineContact. The App has a web page at this address: http://harpy000.appspot.com/. There is also a link to a Twitter page (the owner?), maybe you can contact him.

Comment: Thank you @PowerSp00n.

I have reported the abuse to Google Inc.